# How to check if a new row of inputs is redundant with previous rows (array)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

I have a form which consists of an array of input fields.

Is there any way I could verify the inputs *in every row* and check if they *have at least one unique value* in any one field so that there will be none identical rows?

For example, 2nd row is allowed to only have 3 out of 4 fields with exact values similar to those in 1st row, at max.

```
<form>
     <div>
        <table>
            <tr v-for="(item, i) of items" :key="i">
                <td>
                    <input type="date" :id="'date-' + i">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" :id="'project_id-' + i">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" :id="'hours-' + i">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" :id="'description-' + i">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" @click="itemCount++">Add Row</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" v-on:click="submit()">
    </div>
</form>
```

I have came across a technique using [`distinct`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-distinct)validation but uncertain of its practicality besides of the correct syntax and flow.

Comment: if you could explain bit I think we may able to help you

Comment: @NipunTharuksha, actually I would want to check the user's inputs row by row before the form submit, whether there are two or more rows that are redundant (user shouldn't be allowed to key in the same values of every fields in in every row).

Comment: so you will pass only distinct ids from frontend to backend

Comment: Is there any method/ technique to verify/ validate the inputs before the form submit, for example to mark that as redundancy error and alert the user of that error?

Comment: you can validate your data before pass in to backend at SUBMITTED() method

Comment: at submit function loop each id and push it to a array. before push check does array contain same value. Just a example there are many ways you can achive this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `submit()` function, convert the `items` array to a `Set` in order to remove the redundant values. Next, re-convert to `Array` again to be able to compare the two arrays by their `length`. If the lengths are different, then it means there is(are) redundant value(s) existed.

```js
submit() {
    const arr = this.items        
    var obj = arr.map(JSON.stringify)      
    var set = new Set(obj)
    var unique = Array.from(set).map(JSON.parse)              
    console.log(obj, set, unique);

    if(obj.length != unique.length) {
        alert("Error: Redundant inputs!")
    } else {
        // submit the form
    };
}
```

**STEPS**:

- First, convert each object of the `arr` array into a JSON encoded string using `JSON.stringify` method.
- Secondly, map the JSON encoded string to a new array `obj` using the `map()` method.
- Thirdly, create a new `set` by passing the `obj` array to the new set constructor to remove all the duplicate elements.

  This `set` will only holds the values that are unique from the array.
- Then, convert the set to another array `unique` using the `from()` method by passing the `set` as a parameter.

  This new array will not have any redundant objects from the previous array (if any).
- Lastly, compare both arrays by their `length` to find out if they are equal or not. Unequal lengths indicate the presence of redundant input values.